Missing Content when Printing a tikzposter
I have spent quite a bit of time to create a conference poster using the
tikzposter template, which digitally, looks perfectly fine, and also looks
fine when printed with normal printers.
However, when I sent this to our local print-shop to actually print it in
full-scale as an A0 poster; effectively all content in the columns and blocks
are inexplicably gone. Content outside the columns/blocks were kept, e.g., a
background image, the tikzposter acknowledgement footer, etc.
In their place, we received a second, new page with one of the following error
messages, which I assume is some kind of PostScript error:
ERROR: rangecheck
OFFENDING COMMAND: shfill

STACK:

-dictionary-

ERROR: rangecheck
OFFENDING COMMAND: makepattern

STACK:

[1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 ]
-dictionary-

As far as I can tell, which of these we get seemed to vary depending on which
packages were being used (e.g., the transparent package).
The people at the print-shop did also show me a bit of their machines, so I
think they're using some kind of proprietary Xerox machine with some software
that I think is called "Xerox FreeFlow", but I was not able to find much else
about it that could explain these issues. So far, we have also tried the
following:

Removing all raster graphics.
Removing all raster and vector graphics.
Compiling with LuaLaTeX
Compiling with XeLaTeX
Compiling with XeLaTeX and re-interpreting with Ghostscript to PDF
compatibility version 4.

Nothing really seems to change however.
So, even with quite a bit of googling I am at a loss at how to debug this
further. Even when stripping out effectively everything (e.g., see the included
code), the problem remains. Has anyone encountered and fixed an issue like this
before? Or what else could I do to try to fix this before I have to abandon this
poster template altogether?
Code
% Default values for poster format options.
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm,
blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter}

\usepackage{fontspec}

% Workaround to handle bug in tikzposter.cls.
\makeatletter
\define@key{title}{titletextscale}{\def\TP@titletextscale{#1}}
\makeatletter

\makeatletter
\newcounter{tablecounter}
\newenvironment{tikztable}[1][]{
  \def \rememberparameter{#1}
  \vspace{10pt}
  \refstepcounter{tablecounter}
  \begin{center}
  }{
    \ifx\rememberparameter\@empty
    \else
    \\[10pt]
    {\small Tab.~\thetablecounter: \rememberparameter}
    \fi
  \end{center}
}
\makeatother


% Shows small comment on how the poster was made at bottom of poster.
\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofon

% \setromanfont{Times New Roman}
% \setsansfont{Arial}

% Use LU recommended fonts.
\setromanfont{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\setsansfont{Frutiger LT Std}

% Use the San-Serif font family by default.
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}


\graphicspath{{./img}{./../../res/img}{./build}}

% Define the primary colors used by LTH.
\definecolor{lthBlue}{HTML}{22458a}
\definecolor{lthBronze}{HTML}{875e29}
\definecolor{lthCopper-25}{HTML}{f0f7f1}
\definecolor{lthCopper-50}{HTML}{d9ebdb}
\definecolor{lthCopper}{HTML}{b4d7b8}
\definecolor{lthDark-25}{HTML}{dbdbda}
\definecolor{lthDark-50}{HTML}{a6a5a1}
\definecolor{lthDark}{HTML}{4d4c44}
\definecolor{lthFlower-25}{HTML}{fef8f9}
\definecolor{lthFlower-50}{HTML}{fdeeef}
\definecolor{lthFlower}{HTML}{fcdee0}
\definecolor{lthPlaster-25}{HTML}{f9f8f5}
\definecolor{lthPlaster-50}{HTML}{f0eee5}
\definecolor{lthPlaster}{HTML}{e2ddcb}
\definecolor{lthSky-25}{HTML}{f1f7f9}
\definecolor{lthSky-50}{HTML}{dcebf0}
\definecolor{lthSky}{HTML}{bad8e1}
\definecolor{lthStone-25}{HTML}{f2f1f0}
\definecolor{lthStone-50}{HTML}{dedbd9}
\definecolor{lthStone}{HTML}{beb7b3}

\definecolor{lthFlowerDark}{HTML}{DBADB1}
\definecolor{lthSkyDark}{HTML}{A4C4CF}
\definecolor{lthCopperDark}{HTML}{99BEA7}
\definecolor{lthPlasterDark}{HTML}{CBC5A9}
\definecolor{lthStoneDark}{HTML}{B4A89A}

% Adjust colorpalette to the LTH colors.
\definecolorpalette{LTHColorPalette}{
  \definecolor{colorOne}{named}{lthBronze}
  \definecolor{colorTwo}{named}{lthPlaster}
  \definecolor{colorThree}{named}{lthCopper}
}


% Commands
\newcommand{\bs}{\textbackslash}                  % Backslash
\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{{\bfseries \color{red}#1}}   % Highlights command

% Title, Author, Institute
\title{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering
    Efficient GPU Programming}}
\author{John Doe}
\institute{Faculty of Engineering (LTH), Lund University}

% -- PREDEFINED THEMES ---------------------- %
% Choose LAYOUT:  Default, Basic, Rays, Simple, Envelope, Wave, Board, Autumn, Desert,
\usetheme{Autumn}
\usecolorstyle[colorPalette=LTHColorPalette]{Germany}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{columns}%blocks will be placed into columns
  \column{.55}
  \block[roundedcorners=40]{Creating the document}{
    The document begins with:
    \begin{quote}
      \texttt{\bs documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=10mm, innermargin=15mm,
        blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm]\{tikzposter\}\\
        \bs title\{Title\}\\
        \bs author\{Author(s)\}\\
        \bs institute\{Institute \}\\
        \bs titlegraphic\{Logo\}\\
        \bs begin\{document\}\\
        \bs maketitle}
      \\ \dots \end{quote}
    \begin{tikzfigure}[A figure can be made with \bs \texttt{tikzfigure}; \bs\texttt{figure} does not work]
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[draw=none,inner color=red, outer color=green] (0,0) circle (1.5cm);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{tikzfigure}
    \innerblock[]{Inner Blocks}{Inner blocks may be created inside of blocks with the command \bs\texttt{innerblock[{\it options}]\{{\it Heading}\}\{{\it Text}\}} }
    \coloredbox{Text may be highlighted using colored boxes created by \bs\texttt{coloredbox[{\it options}]\{{\it Text\}}}}
  }
  \note[targetoffsetx=-.05\textwidth,targetoffsety=9.5cm,innersep=.4cm,angle=-45,connection]{Optional arguments for the format of the poster}
  \block{The title matter}{
    The title is made by the standard \texttt{\bs maketitle[{\it options}]} command where you can alter the \texttt{width}, the spacing between the title and top of the poster (\texttt{titletotopverticalspace}), the bottom of the title to the main content of the poster (\texttt{titletoblockverticalspace}) and the space between the title information and the logo (\texttt{titlegraphictotitleverticalspace}).

    If the default format of the title is not to your liking, you can define the placement of the different items via the \texttt{\bs settitle} command, described in the manual.
  }
  \block{Blocks}{
    Blocks are arranged in a grid, by default, with width by default \texttt{\bs textwdith}.  They are created by the command
    \begin{quote}
      \bs\texttt{block [{\it options}] \{{\it title}\}\{{\it contents}\}}
    \end{quote}
    The title may be left empty, resulting in no title area being created for the block (as seen in a later block to the right).  Further blocks will be placed below automatically, at a distance defined by \texttt{blockverticalspace}.

    If you want to change the position of the title matter or the contents in the block, you may by setting in the options
    \begin{quote}
      \texttt{titleoffsetx, titleoffsety, bodyoffsetx, bodyoffsety}
    \end{quote}
    which let you adjust the vertical or horizontal position of the two parts of the block, respectively.  You can also make, relative to the default width, the title and block body by setting
    \begin{quote}
      \texttt{titlewidthscale, bodywidthscale}
    \end{quote}
    The title's alignment can be set by \texttt{titleleft, titlecenter, titleright}, the body may be shifted vertically by setting \texttt{bodyverticalshift}, and the shape of the block can be altered by setting \texttt{roundedcorners, linewidth}. The inner margins of the title can by set by \texttt{titleinnersep,bodyinnersep}.
  }

  \note[targetoffsetx=24cm, targetoffsety=-9cm,rotate=1,angle=270,radius=8cm,width=.75\textwidth,innersep=.4cm]{
    You can place notes that are ``attached'' to the previous block using the command
    \begin{quote} \texttt{\bs note[{\it options}]\{{\it contents}\}}\end{quote}
    The note is placed by default slightly to the right of a ``target'' in the center of the previous block.  The note style may also allow for a connection between the note and the ``target''.  \\
    The target may be shifted from the default by setting the options  \texttt{targetoffsetx, targetoffsety}, rotated by an angle with \texttt{rotate}, and its width with \texttt{width}.  The placement of the note in relation with the target is given in polar coordinates with \texttt{ radius, angle}. Please observe that notes are always drawn {\bfseries over} the other objects. They do not affect the placement of blocks.
  }

  \column{.45}
  \block{Columns}{
    By default, blocks are arranged in a single column. If you want multiple columns for your poster, you may use the \texttt{columns} environment. For example,
    \begin{quote}
      \texttt{\noindent \bs begin\{columns\}\\
        \bs column\{.6\}\\
        \bs block\{\dots\}\{\dots\}\\
        \bs column\{.4\}\\
        \bs block\{\dots\}\{\dots\}\\
        \bs block\{\dots\}\{\dots\}\\
        \bs end\{columns\}
      }
    \end{quote}
    will create two columns of 60\% and 40\% the available width; spacing between successive columns is handled automatically.  The block command(s) following \texttt{\bs column} are the blocks to go in that column.  The number of columns is free to be chosen, but the relative widths must all be chosen.  If the widths sum to less than 1, empty space will be seen on the right.  If they sum to more than 1, the latter columns will be cut off.
  }

  \begin{subcolumns}
    \subcolumn{.45}
    \block{Subcolumns}{If you want to have an additional subdivision of columns inside a column, you may use the\\ \texttt{\bs subcolumns} environment inside of a column environment.  The functionality is similar to that of columns, but now the widths are relative to the width of the current column.}

    \subcolumn{.5}
    \block{}{An example use of subcolumns is.
      \begin{quote}
        \texttt{\bs begin\{subcolumns\}\\
          \bs subcolumn\{.6\}\\
          \bs block\{\dots\}\{\dots\}\\
          \bs subcolumn\{.4\}\\
          \bs block\{\dots\}\{\dots\}\\
          \bs block\{\dots\}\{\dots\}\\
          \bs end\{subcolumns\}
        }
      \end{quote}
    }
  \end{subcolumns}

  \block[titlewidthscale=.8,bodywidthscale=.9,titleoffsety=9.5mm,bodyoffsety=9mm]{Changing the Poster's Appearance}{
    If the default appearance of the title, background, blocks, and notes is not desired, you may change the colors by calling the color style along with a general layout theme with the commands
    \begin{quote}
      \texttt{\bs usecolorpalette}\{{\em color palette}\}\\
      \texttt{\bs usecolorstyle\{{\em color style}\}}
    \end{quote}
    and
    \begin{quote}
      \texttt{\bs usetheme\{{\em layout style}\}}
    \end{quote}
    where the color palette and style and layout style are either the name of a custom made or one of the offered predefined choices listed in the manual or the comments of this poster's source.  Individual changes can be made to the style of the  background, title matter, blocks, inner blocks, and notes by using one of the following (along with either a custom-designed style or a predefined style listed in the manual or the comments of this poster's source).  These changes are made with the commands
    \begin{quote}
      \texttt{\bs usebackgroundstyle[]\{\}, \bs usetitlestyle[]\{\},\\ \bs useblockstyle[]\{\},\bs innerblockstyle[]\{\}, \bs usenotestyle[]\{\}}
    \end{quote}
    Custom styles for these can be made; this is detailed in the manual.
  }

\end{columns}

\block[titleoffsety=-1cm,bodyoffsety=-1cm]{Sample document}{\vspace{2em}
  This poster was created by the following commands (omitting the contents of the blocks and notes) to give a sense of how different objects are created and options used.
  \begin{quote}
    \texttt{\bs documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm,
      blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm]\{tikzposter\}\\
      \bs title\{Using tikzposter\} \bs author\{Pascal Richter, Elena Botoeva, Richard Barnard, \& Dirk Surmann\} \bs institute\{\}\\
      \bs usetheme\{Autumn\}\bs usecolorstyle[colorPalette=BrownBlueOrange]\{Germany\}\\
      \bs begin\{document\}\bs maketitle\\
      \bs begin\{columns\} \bs column\{0.55\}\\
      \bs block\{Creating the document\}\{The document\dots\} \bs note[targetoffsetx=-.05\bs textwidth,targetoffsety=9.5cm,innersep=.4cm,angle=-45,connection]\{\dots\}\\
      \bs block\{The title matter\}\{The title\dots\}\\
      \bs block\{Blocks\}\{Blocks are\dots\} \bs note[targetoffsetx=24cm, targetoffsety=-9cm,rotate=1,angle=270,radius=8cm,width=.75\bs textwidth,innersep=.4cm]\{You can\dots\}\\
      \bs column\{0.45\} \bs block\{Columns\}\{By default,\dots\}\\
      \bs begin\{subcolumns\} \bs subcolumn\{.45\}
      \bs block\{Subcolumns\}\{If you\dots\}
      \bs subcolumn\{.5\} \bs block\{\}\{An example\dots\}
      \bs end\{subcolumns\}\\
      \bs block[titlewidthscale=.8,bodywidthscale=.9,titleoffsety=9.5mm,bodyoffsety=9mm]\{Changing the Poster's Appearance\}\{If the default\dots\}
      \bs end\{columns\}\\
      \bs block[titleoffsety=-1cm,bodyoffsety=-1cm]\{Sample document\}\{This poster\dots\}\\
      \bs end\{document\}
    }
  \end{quote}
}

\end{document}

\endinput


off-topic: don't use two-letter font switches in latex (except, possibly, \em) e.g. \it is wrong. use \itshape or \textit{} instead. \endinput is pointless. which error does the code you posted produce and which parts of it don't get printed? I doubt this is the problem, but mixing colour models can create issues, though probably just colour-related ones.

All code is actually the default tikzposter template with some fixes, but I can fix those nits you found a bit later. As I mentioned in the beginning, though, the code compiles just fine and is visually fine when viewing it. It's when you physically print it that they disappear

I understand and that makes it much more difficult for anybody here to debug. but that's even less likely if we don't even have a match between code and error i.e. when you use this code, which errors are produced? right now, all we know is that the error varies and some code or other produces each of the errors in your question. but that means we have not even one case of code and corresponding error.
